# "Click to show" text at pages

Tags: 7, database, javascript, ajax

How can I implement "click to show" some text data at pages?
Also I need to save log in database about events.

I've found tiny module [Field Value Loader (Show field on click)](https://www.drupal.org/project/fvl).

Any suggestions about how to implement this?

Comment: I think you will need custom jquery.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout these modules:

**[qTip (Stylish jQuery Tooltips)](https://www.drupal.org/project/qtip):**

> qTips are stylish tooltips that can be configured and styled (more to come in later releases) to fit nearly any website's design. You can look at [demo](http://qtip2.com/demos) here.

**[Field Tooltips](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_tooltips):**

> Field Tooltips provides a user interface for adding tooltips to fields. Field Tooltips includes three important features:
>
> 1. A simple administration interface for adding tooltips to fields.
> 2. Support for all field types.
> 3. Support for HTML tooltips.

**[Beauty Tips](https://www.drupal.org/project/beautytips):**

> The Beautytips module provides ballon-help style tooltips for any page element by integrating the BeautyTips jQuery Tooltip plugin by Jeff Robbins with Drupal. It provides an API for adding custom beautytips as well as some built-in features. Admins can enable rollover balloon-help style tooltips for text fields within forms. It also supplies hover tips for Drupal help links and advanced help links.
>
> Most importantly, it allows developers to add their own custom beautytips popups to their site without having to delve into jQuery.